# How to find # of your answers that were accepted

Tags: support, accepted-answer, profile-page

Is there any way to find the number of my answers that have been accepted?

On my profile page, I can see that I've answered 156 times, but I'd like to know how many of those answers were accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+isaccepted%3A1 and start counting, using the pagination for the big chunks. Plugging in your user id instead of user:me (since that would search *my* answers), it appears you currently have 55 accepted answers.

Or, you could use the [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) to run a query to find all accepted answers since the last data dump (monthly). [Here you go](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/8016/?UserId=303911).

Comment: I'm actually surprised to see that you can't get this information easily with the API.

Comment: Cool, thanks. The links to the data explorer stuff aren't working for me - is it down?

Comment: @Jamie: Yeah, it's been having availability issues lately. Try again in a few hours. But as I said, the most up-to-date count will be found using the 1st method.